# Finding unique count using a criterion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate unique records from data like this:

```
NAME MONTH
A   MAY
A   MAY
A   JUNE
B   JULY
B   APRIL
B   DEC
C   OCT
C   SEPT
C   AUG
C   MAR
.   .
.   .
```

ranging from A till infinite so I do not have a list of names where I can use this simple COUNTIFS function:

```
countifs(name,"A",month,"May")
```

I want output in this format:

```
Unique names         May June July
COUNT                 2   3   5
```

That is, unique count of records in each month only.

I have used this function which gives me overall unique set but not monthwise.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(Sheet1!AY2:AY23822,Sheet1!AY2:AY23822))
```

This is the data set and I want a solution like mentioned

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyCXv.png)

Comment: Please remove mysql tag...

Comment: Will `MAY` contain only `A` or it may contain `B`,`C`,etc...? Same way how about other months?

Comment: @ManishChristian - I think that is the point of the unique count. If May had several A's and a few B's then the count would be **2**. If 10 new entries were added with May all being C then the count would be **3**.

Comment: fwiw, i really don't get the downvotes considering the other **I Want** questions around here. Layout of sample data and results although the sample data will not produce the results as well as a *CountUnique* style formula showing at least one of the columns a well as the scope of the data. Seems oh-key-doh-key to me. @pnuts - yeah the sample data should have been able to produce the results shown but count unique formulas require a LOT of rows before they start to make sense.

Comment: @ManishChristian I want unique count of records in May. It can contain A,B or C.

Comment: @pnuts This data set continues till 20000 rows so for an example I quoted 5 for July

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggested formula is a little more complex than is usual but will dynamically adjust the ranges as more entries are added at the bottom.

In E5 (as per sample image) as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:INDEX($B:$B, MATCH("zzz",$A:$A ))=E$4)/(COUNTIFS($B$2:INDEX($B:$B, MATCH("zzz",$A:$A )), E$4, $A$2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH("zzz",$A:$A )), $A$2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH("zzz",$A:$A ))&"")+($B$2:INDEX($B:$B, MATCH("zzz",$A:$A ))<>E$4)))
```

Fill right as necessary. The base formula (with range adjustment removed) is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$15=E$4)/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$15, E$4, $A$2:$A$15, $A$2:$A$15&"")+($B$2:$B$15<>E$4)))
```

[image: Finding Unique count in excel using multiple criteria]

Comment: Thanks I think this is what I wanted but I have one more issue that if the month has some blank cells then how to adjust my formula according to that

Comment: Also can you explain how this logic works.  =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$15=E$4)/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$15, E$4, $A$2:$A$15, $A$2:$A$15&"")+($B$2:$B$15<>E$4)))

Comment: That would depend on what you want to do with the blank cells; count them as a unique entry or discard them altogether. No, tbh I do not have the time or the space to write several paragraphs to explain this (again). You could start with [Count Unique with SUMPRODUCT() Breakdown](http://goo.gl/HKnWQE). Next, step through the formula with the [Evaluate Formula](https://goo.gl/Vl25be) command. Repeat if necessary until you understand it. If some parts are not clear, come back and I will answer specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

May not be suitable for OP but I believe for most with what I'm guessing is the problem a PivotTable would be a good or best solution. The data source would be whole columns to facilitate addition of data (which would require two clicks to refresh the PT) but the `(blank)` column  the whole column source gives rise to could be hidden.

[image: SO3413536 example]

Unfortunately however only available since Excel 2013.

Comment: PowerQuery solution coming soon.